# "Error splitting the argument list: Option not found" or "At least one output file must be specified" depending on the arguments I choose

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, audio-conversion

I'm running into ffmpeg giving me errors when trying to pass arguments to it using an interface I'm creating in XCode/Swift for converting audiobooks.

What ffmpeg should be receiving is:

inputPath = /Volumes/CSW External/ffmpeg/book.aac
outputPath = /Volumes/CSW External/ffmpeg/book.m4b
filters = ffmpegFilters // see below

I've done a 'print" command to the console to be sure that those are the filepaths actually being passed to Xcode. I also have visual confirmation of those filepaths displayed in the app itself.

I have five arrays of arguments that I might choose in my app:

```
                outputExtension = ".mp3"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c:a libmp3lame", "-ac 1", "-ar 22050", "-q:a 9"]
            case 2 :
                outputExtension = ".mp3"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c:a libmp3lame", "-ac 2", "-ar 44100", "-q:a 5"]
            case 3 :
                outputExtension = ".mp3"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c:a libmp3lame", "-ac 1", "-ar 22050", "-b:a 32k"]
            case 4:
                outputExtension = ".flac"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c:a flac"]
            default :
                outputExtension = ".m4b"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c copy"]
```

The ffmpegFilters array is being passed into convertTask.arguments array as a string, so it could either be as short and sweet as `"-c copy"` or as long as `"-c:a libmp3lame -ac 1 -ar 22050 -b:a 32k"`

If I choose the last one (.m4b) I get the error:

```
Unrecognized option 'c copy'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

I tried using `"--c copy"` instead (because - is a mathematical operator in Swift) and got the same error, only it read "-c copy" instead of "c copy".

For the .mp3 and .flac options it will read my metadata from my input file, telling me that it's at least reading my input location correctly, but then it will give me the error `At least one output file must be specified` which tells me that it's not reading my outputFilePath correctly.

I've tried various ways of formatting the arguments (one long string instead of an array, multiple short strings instead of an array, lead them with two hyphens instead of one, put a whitespace before the hyphen, putting a whitespace in front of the output path) and the result has been that I occasionally see the errors `"Trailing options were found on the commandline"` and `"Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -c:a libmp3lame -ac 1 -ar 22050 -q:a 9'"`

I've spent the last three days researching these various errors. and it seems that last one seems to happen most often when people's arguments are formatted improperly. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong with my arguments?

Edit: I suspect in addition to the spaces in the arguments instead of separating them where the spaces fall, the problem was also the way that array of arguments was being passed into the process that runs ffmpeg. To get around that, I've gone a different route. It's not working yet, but at least the error is different.

Comment: On the command line, spaces separate arguments (unless they're quoted or escaped); you seem to be treating them as *part of* arguments, which I'm pretty sure is the problem. You want `ffmpegFilters = ["-c", "copy"]`, etc.

Comment: I actually did try it that way a couple days ago. I was getting the same errors.

I am beginning to suspect at least some of the issue is the way that the variables I'm defining in other methods are being passed into the (like inputFilePath, ffmpegFilters, outputFilePath) process to run ffmpeg. When I coded them directly into the process, it didn't work, but the error I got changed to "operation not permitted"?

Comment: I think some of the problem also was that I was using `filters: ffmpegFilters.joined()` when calling the function. I've found a different, albeit repetitive, way to do it, that seems to get me further. Editing my post. Now I just have to contend with the "Operation Not Permitted" error.

Comment: Thank you for answering!